# dynamically creating tablelayout (android)

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I want to create inner tablelayout and add there 1 row with 2 columns, following code shows nothing, why?

Here's main activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv1.setText("Hello1!");
    tv2.setText("Hello2!");
    TableLayout layoutINNER = new TableLayout(this);
    layoutINNER.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(params);
    tr.addView(tv1);
    tr.addView(tv2);
    layoutINNER.addView(tr);
    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
    main.addView(layoutINNER);
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/android:main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

UPDATE:

Well, finally i solved this problem, it was just needed to use TableRow.LayoutParams with TextViews, not LinearLayout.LayoutParams or some other

Comment: Have you tried using `TableLayout.LayoutParams` instead for your `TextViews` and the `TableRow`?

Comment: Here's what you're looking for: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/

Comment: i've tried recently, it doesn't work too

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
    android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams trparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    tv1.setText("Hello1!");
    tv2.setText("Hello2!");
    TableLayout layoutINNER = new TableLayout(this);
    layoutINNER.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

    tr.setLayoutParams(params);
    tr.addView(tv1);
    tr.addView(tv2);
    layoutINNER.addView(tr);
    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
    main.addView(layoutINNER);
}
}
```