# How can i add table row in table layout?

Tags: android

Here i have referenced code [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5727771/how-to-generate-dynamic-textview-in-android)

I have to add multiple textviews @ runtime and maybe its working but textviews are not shown and I have to add table row in table layout and show textview. But its not working.

Here is my code :

```
tx[i] = new TextView(S1.this);

                    tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tx[i].setText(name);

                    tr[i] = new TableRow(S1.this);
                    tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tr[i].addView(tx[i]);
                    rl.addView(tr[i]); // Exception
```

Here exception is thrown and app stops working.

Here is my logcat :

```
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): Process: com.app.crossdine, PID: 1716
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at com.app.crossdine.S1$Getitems.doInBackground(S1.java:155)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at com.app.crossdine.S1$Getitems.doInBackground(S1.java:1)
04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 04-08 02:13:05.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Please guide me.

Comment: what exception is thrown? please post logcat

Comment: What is rl in your code?

Comment: This is not your proper logcat from where we can solve your problem. Post full logcat.

Comment: rl is the object of relativelayout

Comment: Done full logcat @PiYusHGuPtA

Comment: What are you performing in `doInBackground()` method?

Comment: rl should be the table layout, as shown in the example in your link.

Comment: then where should i create table layout? @user1226136

Comment: @kittu, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the link provided in the question and also the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355853/dynamically-creating-tablelayout-android), you can use it like below (make sure the `rl` is properly pointing to the layout/view you are adding this table to).

UPDATE: Because you are using AsyncTask, you can not modify the UI content in this method. I did in onPostExecute method. Also, you should set the layout parameters of the TextView with `TableRow.LayoutParams`. My working code below

First added the following to a button in my xml layout

```
android:onClick="addTable"
```

Then added the following the the java activity

```
public void addTable(View view){
    CreateTableTask mTask = new CreateTableTask();
    mTask.execute();
}

public class CreateTableTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, TableLayout> {
@Override
protected TableLayout doInBackground(Void... params) {
    LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableLayout layoutINNER = new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);
    layoutINNER.setLayoutParams(params1);
    TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        tx[i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tx[i].setText("Data");
    tr[i] = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
    tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr[i].addView(tx[i]);
    // and then adding table row in tablelayout
    layoutINNER.addView(tr[i]);
    }
    return layoutINNER;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final TableLayout newTable) {
    if (newTable!=null) {
            // this rl is the layout where I want this table
        View rl= findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        ((ViewGroup) rl).addView(newTable);             
    } 
}       
}
```

Comment: when i am writing following line layoutINNER.addView(tr[i]); it gives me same exception as above on that line

Comment: @kittu, are you adding this view in the doInBackground method of your asynctask?

Comment: I implemented the same thing in asynctask without problem. See the updated code and see if you can make anything out of it. @kittu

Comment: I cant find r.id.RelativeLayout ? What should i do ?@user1226136

Comment: at xml layout make sure you defined the id tag (e.g. in my case I added the following attribute to the linear layout of my choice `android:id="@+id/mainlayout"` ) and then you should be able find the id in your code.